# how to aggregate pandas data into flat dataframe (without hierarchical indexes)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data of measurements at two time values with replicates:

```
name    t   value   replicate
foo 1   0.5 a
foo 1   0.55    b
foo 1   0.6 c
foo 2   0.7 a
foo 2   0.71    b
foo 2   0.72    c
bar 1   0.1 a
bar 1   0.12    b
bar 1   0.3 c
bar 2   0.4 a
bar 2   0.45    b
bar 2   0.44    c
```

I want to parse it into dataframe and get the mean and standard deviation of the replicates for each time point ("t" column) and for each sample ("name" column). This can be done with:

```
df = pandas.read_table("data.txt",sep="\t")
g = df.groupby(["name", "t"])
new_df = g.agg([np.mean, np.std])
```

The problem is that `new_df` has a *hierarchical* index:

```
           value          
            mean       std
name t                    
bar  1  0.173333  0.110151
     2  0.430000  0.026458
foo  1  0.550000  0.050000
     2  0.710000  0.010000
```

How can I get a flat dataframe instead where the mean and std values are just regular columns? I tried `reset_index()` but that does not do it:

```
>>> new_df.reset_index()
  name  t     value          
               mean       std
0  bar  1  0.173333  0.110151
1  bar  2  0.430000  0.026458
2  foo  1  0.550000  0.050000
3  foo  2  0.710000  0.010000
```

i'd like the final dataframe to have columns: `sample, t, mean, std` (or `value_mean, value_std`). How can this be done in pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something slightly different from MaxU.  Try resetting the index to a specific column level and then drop the other column level(s).

```
In [5]: new_df2 = new_df.copy()

In [6]: new_df2 = new_df2.reset_index(col_level=1)

In [7]: new_df2.columns = new_df2.columns.get_level_values(1) # same level=1

In [8]: new_df2
Out[8]: 
  name  t      mean       std
0  bar  1  0.173333  0.110151
1  bar  2  0.430000  0.026458
2  foo  1  0.550000  0.050000
3  foo  2  0.710000  0.010000
```

Edit:

With `MultiIndex`s, which can be used to setup a multi-level arrangement of either your index (vertical column) or column labels (your case), the column labels are stored as `levels` and their positions are stored as `labels`.  Like this:

```
In [4]: df.columns
Out[4]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'value'], [u'mean', u'std']],
           labels=[[0, 0], [0, 1]])
```

By doing `reset_index(col_level=1)`, we transform the MultiIndex into

```
In [5]: df.reset_index(col_level=1).columns
Out[5]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'value', u''], [u'mean', u'std', u't', u'name']],
           labels=[[1, 1, 0, 0], [3, 2, 0, 1]])
```

which takes the labels out of the Index and puts them into level 1 (the second/lower level) of the column MultiIndex.  Then `columns = columns.get_level_values(1)` grabs the values of the column labels at level 1, and sets only those values as the column labels, effectively dropping level 0.

```
 Out[6]: Index([u'name', u't', u'mean', u'std'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: can you explain what get_level_values does here?

Answer (score 2):

try to rename your columns:

```
In [9]: new_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

let's set the column names in the following way: take `level==1` column if it exists, otherwise take column with `level==0`

```
In [14]: new_df.columns = [c[1] if c[1] else c[0] for c in new_df.columns.tolist()]

In [15]: new_df
Out[15]:
  name  t      mean       std
0  bar  1  0.173333  0.110151
1  bar  2  0.430000  0.026458
2  foo  1  0.550000  0.050000
3  foo  2  0.710000  0.010000
```

Comment: can you explain what your code does and whether it will generalize? is there a pandas built in that does the same?

Comment: @mvd, i've added a comment to my answer - please check